# Can I install rigid foam between my rafters to insulate?

Tags: insulation

Can I double up on an 2" Foamular insulation board to create an R-20 value in my 2x6 rafters Do I cut the foam at the exact 14 1/2" opening or do I cut it at 13 1/2" or 14"

Comment: Attics are where more is always better for insulation.  R-20 probably at the minimum you want.  This is true for most cool/cold climates.

Comment: Does your attic have a ceiling?

Comment: Apparently it works well. My son had a house built about 10years ago and the attic has sprayed foam , which is solid after a few minutes. In a hot area of Texas and he says his AC cost is reasonable indicating the foam is insulating well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, though it's a relatively expensive way to insulate an attic.

Blown cellulose is usually the best bang for the buck, and does not need to be cut to fit. But you do need a mask; and a bath and some vacuuming after installation.

Rockwool bats come pre-cut and can be fit even if the spacing is slightly varying.

But, if committed to foamboard, If your joist spacing is precise and consistent, cut to the exact spacing so they friction-fit in. If they vary, cut a bit smaller and consider adding some spray foam to seal the gaps - or cut to 14.5" and use a rasp to deal with any tight spots when installing. Stagger the joints between layers.

Answer (score 1):

**No. Well, yes. Sort of.**

The R value of a panel is only as good as the average of the insulation performance of all its components. In the case of framing lumber, it's around 1.25 per inch of depth, or 5 for the depth of the foam panels you plan to use. If we assume 1½" rafters at 16" intervals, the lumber composes roughly 10% of the total area. This means that your total R-value will be calculated thusly:

R = .10 x 5 + .90 x 20 = 18.45.

Of course, this depends on near perfect fitment and/or full-depth sealing with spray foam afterward. Your actual outcome will probably be more like R-12 to R-15. You could improve this to near R-20 by putting the foam *over* (under) the rafters to avoid all those joints and the heat loss of the wood.

**That's probably not what you're actually asking, though.**

Yes, you can do what you describe. You'd cut to fit snugly. Each rafter cavity is likely to be slightly different, and they're likely out of parallel somewhat, so you'll need to take measurements every 4 feet or so and cut accordingly. Or you can hold the panels in place and cut along the rafters. Regardless, this will be somewhat a tedious process.

Once you do that I'd consider some sort of strapping or banding below the rafters to prevent the panels from jiggling out. Seasonal movement and vibration due to sound and vehicle traffic can result in things moving earthward over time. Even plastic lumber bands stapled to the rafters would do.

**A few caveats:**

- You're creating what's known as a "hot roof" unless you keep the insulation to the *bottom* of the rafters to maintain ventilation above. Hot roofs are hard on the roofing above and can result in moisture problems in some climates.
- Ventilation would need to be continuous at the soffit and ridge in order to vent every rafter cavity.
- Depending on local code, you may be required to cover the foam for fire resistance.
- Any air leaks in the system *dramatically* degrade insulation value. If air can pass *around* the insulation it effectively does nothing. Heat travels through insulation via conduction, which is a slow process, but it quickly travels around it in the air. You must maintain a good seal at all joints. Special tape designed for foam panels can help where spray foam is impractical.

Answer (score 0):

Installing rigid insulation under roof joists creates some issues: 1) ventilation between insulation and joists, 2) air space between layers of rigid insulation, 3) trapped moisture in roof system that creates mold.

1. The Building Code requires a minimum of 1” clearance between the bottom of the roof sheathing and the top of the insulation. In addition, that air space must have cross ventilation so condensation can escape.
2. When you install the second layer you’ll be pushing it up into position. If it is not pushed up precisely into position (without an air space) it can allow condensation to be created in that air space. Now, because the boards have a cover (vapor barrier) that moisture will accumulate and run towards the joists and without cross ventilation the moisture will lay against the wood joists and create dryrot.
3. Any moisture (condensation) trapped within the roof system will create dryrot and mold. Installing such an installation so precisely seems unlikely.

See the following report on rigid insulation. Scroll down to page 8 and you’ll see it’s recommended to be installed on top of the structural roof
system, which eliminates all those concerns.

https://cdn.ymaws.com/www.polyiso.org/resource/resmgr/health&environment/EPD_CoverBoard_2020_Final_11.pdf